# Folland chapter 1. Problem 30

Tags: real-analysis

I'm sorry if this question is dumb. I'm not a mathematician, just happened to take an advanced real analysis course... So, Problem 30. I've seen many proofs of this one on the internet, but I don't get why those are so complicated. It seems much simpler to me. Please, let me know where I'm wrong in the proof.

Problem 30. If $E\in \mathcal{L}$ and $\mu(E) > 0$ then for every  $a< 1$ there is an open interval $I$ such that $\mu(E \cap I) > a\mu(I)$.

Proof.

For $\mu(E)<\infty$. From Theorem 1.18 we know that there is an open $I$, such that $E\subset I$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(I)$. Note that $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap I)$, therefore $\mu(E\cap I)=\mu(I)<a\mu(I)$.

For $\mu(E)=\infty$. There is an $n\in Z$, such that $0<\mu(E\cap [n,n+1))<\infty$. As before, there is an open $I'$, s.t. $E\cap [n,n+1)\subset I'$, and $\mu(E\cap I')>\mu(E\cap [n,n+1)\cap I')>a\mu(I')$.

Comment: No, that can't be what Theorem 1.1 says, because it's obviously false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case that $\mu(E)<\infty$, theorem 1.18 tells you that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an open set $U\subset\mathbb R$ with $E\subset U$ and $\mu(U)<\mu(E)+\varepsilon$.  You can't take a "limit" over these open sets and obtain the conclusion you made.

In your proof for the case that $\mu(E)=\infty$, you have the right idea of reducing to the case where $\mu(E)<\infty$, but you can't guarantee that $E\cap [n,n+1)\subset I'$.  All you can say is that there exists some open interval $I'$ such that $\mu(E\cap [n,n+1)\cap I')>a\mu(I')$.

Comment: Right, thank you!